# illegal operation stringstream << stringstream with c++11

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile an existing cpp code with -std=c++11 on solaris11 using the developerstudio12.6 and getting an illegal operation error. The compilation is fine with -std=c++03.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Here is the simplified code:

a.cpp:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::stringstream traceTabName;
   std::stringstream tabName1;

   tabName1 << "hello";
   traceTabName << tabName1;
}
```

- Compiles fine: `/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -std=c++03 -m64 -c a.cpp`
- Compilation error: `/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin/CC -std=c++11 -m64 -c a.cpp`

> "a.cpp", line 10: Error: The operation "std::stringstream << std::stringstream "  is illegal.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `<<` operator that can output one `std::stringstream` to another. However, [there's a `<<` operator that can output a `const void *` pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

In C++03 `std::stringstream` (or, more precisely, its base class `std::basic_ios`) was [implicitly convertible to `void *`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). Which is what happens in C++03 mode to your

```
traceTabName << tabName1;
```

It is interpreted as

```
traceTabName << (void *) tabName1;
```

Starting from C++11 this implicit conversion is no longer available, which is why the code will no longer compile. This conversion has been replaced with conversion to `bool` and, more importantly, it is now declared as `explicit`.

In C++03 it was "compilable" but it did not do what you probably expected it to do anyway. In any version of language specification to implement your intent (as I see it) you'd have to do

```
traceTabName << tabName1.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<<` operator that supports passing a `stringstream` to a `stringstream` in C++11.

This is similar in Clang 5.0 (https://godbolt.org/z/8weXzS)
vs Clang 6.0 (https://godbolt.org/z/Cq09b5) (where it fails):

- Clang 5.0 uses C++03
- Clang 6.0 uses C++11

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::stringstream' (aka
>   'basic_stringstream') and 'std::stringstream')

Answer (score 1):

may be you wanted to do `traceTabName << tabName1.str();` ?